# What's the name of this electrical connector?

Tags: connector

What's the name of this electrical connector?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Mathew. For future reference, please crop your photos. The relevant part of this image is < 20% of the total.

Comment: That looks like a classic welder’s solution to extending the reach... and cable lugs or cable terminals apply.

Comment: Carnival/Fairground bodgy generator connection.

Comment: its called not spending 20 bucks on a new cable

Comment: Note that you need a proper crimp lug tool to make reliable connections. The crimps on the photo are *very* badly done and have paid the price. Please use proper tools!

Comment: it is called a `bolt`

Comment: @Transistor OK I got it,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just two ring crimp terminals connected by a bolt.

It's a terrible job. The left one is badly frayed and the right one is showing signs of burning. There is no easy way to insulate the connection properly.

[image]

*Figure 1. They are designed to be terminated on securely mounted studs - either direct to a chassis or onto a stud mounted on an insulated base. Image source: [Interfacebus](http://www.interfacebus.com/Glossary-of-Terms_terminal-lugs.html).*

Comment: yeah. This looks like a very clear case of "cut off both ends + 4 cm, make new connection, this time properly". Both terminals show that not all strands were properly inserted into the barrel, thus yield bad, unreliable connections that can quickly become a fire hazard.

Answer (score 4):

These are generally referred to as "cable lugs". There are many different styles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In India they are referred to as 'Dowell's cable crimping lugs' or 'Crimping type copper tubular cable terminal ends'.

[image]

Cable crimping is carried out using special crimping tools with interchangeable hexagonal dies.